# 500 server error laravel last version php

Tags: php, laravel

I used this https://codecanyon.net/item/fleetcart-laravel-ecommerce-system/23014826 for my emarket, and i adding invoice in admin panel.

Terminal

```
sie/FleetCart$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 143 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin (v1.4.1): Downloading (connectingDownloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing algolia/algoliasearch-client-php (2.7.0): Downloading (connectingDownloading (100%)         
  - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.5.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.7.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing graham-campbell/result-type (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/process (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.20.0): Downloading (connectiDownloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/mime (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.3.1): Downloading (connecting..Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/error-handler (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/finder (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.20.0): Downloading (connectingDownloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/string (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing ramsey/collection (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing brick/math (0.9.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing opis/closure (3.6.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v2.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (2.41.5): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing monolog/monolog (2.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.5.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/commonmark (1.5.6): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.0.2): Downloading (connecting..Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/framework (v8.11.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing astrotomic/laravel-translatable (v11.9.0): Downloading (connectinDownloading (100%)         
  - Installing sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.3.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing phenx/php-svg-lib (v0.3.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.6): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v0.8.7): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing cache/tag-interop (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing cache/adapter-common (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing cache/filesystem-adapter (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing cartalyst/support (v5.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing cartalyst/sentinel (v5.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing darryldecode/cart (4.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/cache (1.10.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (2.12.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.4.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/promise (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/httplug (2.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/discovery (1.12.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing clue/stream-filter (v1.5.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/message (1.9.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing php-http/curl-client (2.1.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing florianv/exchanger (2.5.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing florianv/swap (4.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.9.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing instamojo/instamojo-php (1.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing jackiedo/dotenv-editor (1.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing laravel/helpers (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/legacy-factories (v1.0.5): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing laravel/scout (v8.4.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing league/oauth1-client (v1.8.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing laravel/socialite (v5.0.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.10.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (v0.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.10.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v2.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing mtdowling/jmespath.php (2.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.158.15): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (1.0.29): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing markbaker/matrix (2.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing markbaker/complex (2.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing myclabs/php-enum (1.7.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing maennchen/zipstream-php (2.1.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.15.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing maatwebsite/excel (3.1.24): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing maatwebsite/laravel-sidebar (2.4.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing mcamara/laravel-localization (1.6.1):Downloading (100%)         )
  - Installing mehedi/laravel-captcha (v3.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing laravelcollective/html (v6.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing mehedi/stylist (dev-master 2cbaace): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing mexitek/phpcolors (v0.4): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing nwidart/laravel-modules (8.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing nyholm/psr7 (1.3.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing paypal/paypalhttp (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing predis/predis (v1.1.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing rmccue/requests (v1.7.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing razorpay/razorpay (2.5.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing drewm/mailchimp-api (v2.5.4): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing spatie/laravel-newsletter (4.8.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing spatie/once (2.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing spatie/schema-org (3.1.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing stripe/stripe-php (v7.61.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing cache/hierarchical-cache (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing swayok/alternative-laravel-cache (5.4.13): Downloading (connectinDownloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.20.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/intl (v5.1.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing tightenco/ziggy (0.9.4): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing typicms/nestablecollection (1.1.20): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle (v9.11.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.4.16): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing maximebf/debugbar (v1.16.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing barryvdh/laravel-debugbar (v3.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing beyondcode/laravel-dump-server (1.6.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing beyondcode/laravel-query-detector (1.4.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing filp/whoops (2.9.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing facade/flare-client-php (1.3.7): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing facade/ignition (2.5.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing nunomaduro/collision (v5.0.2): Loading from cache
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
symfony/http-client-contracts suggests installing symfony/http-client-implementation
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/service-contracts suggests installing symfony/service-implementation
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing true/punycode (Needed to support internationalized email addresses, if ext-intl is not installed)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-gmp (Enables faster math with arbitrary-precision integers using GMP.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Enables the use of PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing paragonie/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (Allow sending log messages to an Elasticsearch server via official client)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via driver))
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via library))
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-memcached (Required to use the memcache cache driver.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-redis (Required to use the Redis cache and queue drivers (^4.0|^5.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use the Flysystem cache (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Required to use the Flysystem SFTP driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing mockery/mockery (Required to use mocking (^1.4.2).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing phpunit/phpunit (Required to use assertions and run tests (^8.5.8|^9.3.3).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/cache (Required to PSR-6 cache bridge (^5.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/filesystem (Required to enable support for relative symbolic links (^5.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to use PSR-7 bridging features (^2.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing wildbit/swiftmailer-postmark (Required to use Postmark mail driver (^3.0).)
dompdf/dompdf suggests installing ext-gmagick (Improves image processing performance)
dompdf/dompdf suggests installing ext-imagick (Improves image processing performance)
doctrine/cache suggests installing alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter (Required to use legacy MongoDB driver)
php-http/discovery suggests installing puli/composer-plugin (Sets up Puli which is recommended for Discovery to work. Check http://docs.php-http.org/en/latest/discovery.html for more details.)
php-http/message suggests installing slim/slim (Used with Slim Framework PSR-7 implementation)
php-http/message suggests installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (Used with Diactoros Factories)
florianv/exchanger suggests installing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (Required to use Guzzle for sending HTTP requests)
guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing laminas/laminas-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 responses)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
aws/aws-sdk-php suggests installing aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator (To validate incoming SNS notifications)
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet suggests installing jpgraph/jpgraph (Option for rendering charts, or including charts with PDF or HTML Writers)
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet suggests installing mpdf/mpdf (Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer)
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet suggests installing tecnickcom/tcpdf (Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer (doesn't yet support PHP8))
predis/predis suggests installing ext-phpiredis (Allows faster serialization and deserialization of the Redis protocol)
swayok/alternative-laravel-cache suggests installing cache/predis-adapter (Required to use Redis-based cache through predis/predis package)
swayok/alternative-laravel-cache suggests installing cache/redis-adapter (Required to use Redis-based cache through php-redis extension (recommended - faster and more stable then predis))
yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle suggests installing yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons (Plugin for server-side exporting of dataTables.)
yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle suggests installing yajra/laravel-datatables-editor (Plugin to use DataTables Editor (requires a license).)
yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle suggests installing yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal (Plugin for server-side response using Fractal.)
yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle suggests installing yajra/laravel-datatables-html (Plugin for server-side HTML builder of dataTables.)
maximebf/debugbar suggests installing kriswallsmith/assetic (The best way to manage assets)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
facade/ignition suggests installing laravel/telescope (^3.1)
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package paypal/paypalhttp is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
Deprecation Notice: Class Modules\Media\Sidebar\SidebarExtender located in ./Modules/Invoice/Sidebar/SidebarExtender.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Modules\Media\Sidebar\SidebarExtender" was found 2x: in "/home/mokoch/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart/Modules/Media/Sidebar/SidebarExtender.php" and "/home/mokoch/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart/Modules/Invoice/Sidebar/SidebarExtender.php", the first will be used.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: astrotomic/laravel-translatable
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-query-detector
Discovered Package: cartalyst/sentinel
Discovered Package: darryldecode/cart
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: jackiedo/dotenv-editor
Discovered Package: laravel/legacy-factories
Discovered Package: laravel/scout
Discovered Package: laravel/socialite
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: mcamara/laravel-localization
Discovered Package: mehedi/laravel-captcha
Discovered Package: mehedi/stylist
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-newsletter
Discovered Package: swayok/alternative-laravel-cache
Discovered Package: tightenco/ziggy
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
66 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package paypal/paypalhttp is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
Deprecation Notice: Class Modules\Media\Sidebar\SidebarExtender located in ./Modules/Invoice/Sidebar/SidebarExtender.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Modules\Media\Sidebar\SidebarExtender" was found 2x: in "/home/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart/Modules/Media/Sidebar/SidebarExtender.php" and "/home/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart/Modules/Invoice/Sidebar/SidebarExtender.php", the first will be used.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: astrotomic/laravel-translatable
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-query-detector
Discovered Package: cartalyst/sentinel
Discovered Package: darryldecode/cart
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: jackiedo/dotenv-editor
Discovered Package: laravel/legacy-factories
Discovered Package: laravel/scout
Discovered Package: laravel/socialite
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: mcamara/laravel-localization
Discovered Package: mehedi/laravel-captcha
Discovered Package: mehedi/stylist
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-newsletter
Discovered Package: swayok/alternative-laravel-cache
Discovered Package: tightenco/ziggy
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
66 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
HP-Laptop-17-by0xxx:~/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart$ php artisan optimize:clearCompiled views cleared!
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
Configuration cache cleared!
Compiled services and packages files removed!
Caches cleared successfully!
HP-Laptop-17-by0xxx:~/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart$ php artisan cache:clear
Application cache cleared!
HP-Laptop-17-by0xxx:~/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart$ php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!
HP-Laptop-17-by0xxx:~/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart$ php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
HP-Laptop-17-by0xxx:~/Documents/russia/marketplacesalondebeautérussie/FleetCart$ php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:21 2020] PHP 7.4.11 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:39 2020] 127.0.0.1:60122 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:60122 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:60142 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:60142 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/css/app.css?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:60142 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:60144 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:60144 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/js/app.js?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:60144 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60146 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60146 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/fonts/la-solid-900.woff2
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60146 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60150 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60150 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/fonts/la-regular-400.woff2
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60150 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60154 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60154 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/images/arrow-black.png
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:46 2020] 127.0.0.1:60154 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:48 2020] 127.0.0.1:60158 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:49 2020] 127.0.0.1:60158 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:49 2020] 127.0.0.1:60162 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:49 2020] 127.0.0.1:60162 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/css/app.css?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:49 2020] 127.0.0.1:60162 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:49 2020] 127.0.0.1:60164 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:49 2020] 127.0.0.1:60164 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/js/app.js?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:49 2020] 127.0.0.1:60164 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:50 2020] 127.0.0.1:60168 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:50 2020] 127.0.0.1:60168 [200]: GET /themes/storefront/public/images/arrow-black.png
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:50 2020] 127.0.0.1:60168 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:55 2020] 127.0.0.1:60170 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:56 2020] 127.0.0.1:60170 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:56 2020] 127.0.0.1:60174 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:56 2020] 127.0.0.1:60174 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60180 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60182 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60186 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60188 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60182 [200]: GET /modules/admin/css/admin.css?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60180 [200]: GET /modules/user/admin/css/login.css?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60188 [200]: GET /modules/user/admin/js/login.js?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60180 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60182 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60188 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60186 [200]: GET /modules/admin/js/admin.js?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:57 2020] 127.0.0.1:60186 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:58 2020] 127.0.0.1:60192 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:58 2020] 127.0.0.1:60192 [200]: GET /modules/admin/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
[Tue Nov 10 09:07:58 2020] 127.0.0.1:60192 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:06 2020] 127.0.0.1:60208 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:07 2020] 127.0.0.1:60208 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:07 2020] 127.0.0.1:60212 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:07 2020] 127.0.0.1:60212 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60218 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60218 [200]: GET /modules/admin/css/admin.css?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60218 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60220 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60220 [200]: GET /modules/admin/css/dashboard.css?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60220 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60222 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60222 [200]: GET /modules/admin/js/admin.js?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60222 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60224 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60224 [200]: GET /modules/admin/js/dashboard.js?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:08 2020] 127.0.0.1:60224 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:09 2020] 127.0.0.1:60226 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:08:12 2020] 127.0.0.1:60226 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:11:18 2020] 127.0.0.1:60496 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:11:23 2020] 127.0.0.1:60496 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Tue Nov 10 09:11:23 2020] 127.0.0.1:60496 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:25 2020] 127.0.0.1:60686 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:25 2020] 127.0.0.1:60686 [200]: GET /modules/admin/css/admin.css?v=2.0.6
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:25 2020] 127.0.0.1:60686 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:26 2020] 127.0.0.1:60692 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:26 2020] 127.0.0.1:60692 [200]: GET /modules/admin/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:26 2020] 127.0.0.1:60692 Closing
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:28 2020] 127.0.0.1:60694 Accepted
[Tue Nov 10 09:12:33 2020] 127.0.0.1:60694 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
```

For first i try to delete vendor file and do composer install, after i have all what you see. When i go in others pages in admin panel it's worked but page for create invoice dont woked. Someone do this in windows me i use ubuntu. And i have this  500 Server Error only in one page and i dont know how i can remove this, for i can continu project. I have this error 500 when i click in invoice but others requirements in admin panel dont worked too...

Answer (score 2):

Your installation is ok, but you must configure ownership and permission of storage and bootstrap/cache folder.

- Change the ownership folders

  `sudo chown YOUR_USERNAME:www-data -R storage`

  `sudo chown YOUR_USERNAME:www-data -R bootstrap/cache`
- Then change the folder permissions

  `sudo chmod 775 -R storage`

  `sudo chmod 775 -R bootstrap/cache`